# Generating chi_squared using best fit

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis, chi-squared

I am generating 1000 iterations of some fake data set and using curve_fit to find the best fitting model (A gaussian with certain mean, offset,amp...) Instead of guessing the mean value of my fitting model, use curve_fit so that I can have better chi2 values.
But now the output is weird and even the data and the model don't agree.[image: This is the scatter plots of my data and fitting model]

Also, if I plot a histogram of my chi2 values, [image: The chi2_fit values don't spread out like expected]

```
true_mean = 5 #Assume that we know the perfect fitting model is gaussian 
#with mean value 5. And use try_mean with different mean values to see how 
#does the chi2 behave
true_amp = 100
true_wid = 2
true_offset =10
x_values =  np.array([i for i in np.arange(0,10,0.4)])
exact_y_values = np.array([true_offset + true_amp*
                               np.exp(-((i-true_mean)/true_wid)**2)
                               for i in x_values])
    

    
try_mean = 4.8   # Notice the data is generated centered at 5;
# by comparing it to a 4.8 we expect disagreement.
try_amp = 100
try_wid = 2  
try_offset =10
try_these_y_values = np.array([try_offset + try_amp*
                                   np.exp(-((i-try_mean)/try_wid)**2)
                                   for i in x_values])

def func (x_values,offset,amp,mean,wid):
    return (offset + amp*np.exp(-((i-mean)/wid)**2))
#Excercise 2
#def func (x_values,offset,amp,mean,wid): return (offset + amp*np.exp(-((i-mean)/wid)**2))

chi2_fit=np.zeros(1000)
for i in range (1000):

    fake_exp_y_values = np.array([np.random.poisson(y)
                                      for y in exact_y_values])
    p01=[true_offset,true_amp,true_mean,true_wid]
    [popt,pcov]=opt.curve_fit(func,x_values, fake_exp_y_values,p01)
    y_values_fit=np.array([popt[0]+ popt[1]
                           *np.exp(
                               -((x_values-popt[2])/popt[3])**2)])
    residuals=fake_exp_y_values-y_values_fit
    y_err=np.clip(np.sqrt(fake_exp_y_values),1,9999)
    pulls=residuals/y_err
    chi2_fit[i]=np.sum(pulls**2)
    
plt.hist(chi2_fit)
plt.scatter(x_values,exact_y_values,color='k',ls='--',
            label='true model')
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values_fit,color='r')
plt.errorbar(x_values,y_values_fit,yerr=y_err)
```

What should be modified in order to have a reasonable plot.[image: something like this]
[image: And the histogram should be like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definition of your function and usage of `i`:

```py
def func (x_values,offset,amp,mean,wid):
    return (offset + amp*np.exp(-((i-mean)/wid)**2))

for i in range (1000):
    ...
    [popt,pcov]=opt.curve_fit(func,x_values, fake_exp_y_values,p01)
    ...
```

Corrected version:

```py
def func (x_values,offset,amp,mean,wid):
    return (offset + amp*np.exp(-((x_values-mean)/wid)**2))
```

Also please next time post [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This one was not minimal and not reproduciable (I had to add `y_values_fit = y_values_fit.flatten()` at the end to make it work).

Comment: Oh the function is something I defined for the previous question and it should be fine. But I added flatted() at the end of y_values_fit and it worked. I am a bit confused about how this solved the problem? Can you give me some further explanation so I can have a better understanding? Either way it solved my question and I appreciate your help a lot! Thanks

Comment: The version you posted had `x_values` argument, but it was no used. Instead, you used variable `i`, which was used for other purpose.